Three Wind Quartets (Gambaro) -- notes lengths don't add up (3.75 beats in common time)
I'm transcribing the first movement of Gambaro's Three Wind Quartets, and I came across this part in the Clarinet part:
Clarinet in C part

I'm seeing the following:

a dotted eighth note (.75 beats)
a sixteenth note (.25 beats)
a dotted quarter note (1.5 beats)
a sixteenth note (.25 beats)
a dotted eighth note (.75 beats)
a sixteenth note (.25 beats)

If you sum the beats, you get 3.75 beats. This work is in common time.
What gives?

You're right, there's a bit missing. Are the surrounding bars containing the same sort of rhythm?

There's a carbon copy of this rhythm about 6 measures down. If you want, you can find this work on IMSLP (Gambaro, Three Wind Quartets, Clarinet in C) to see the full context.

The dots are there, they're just misaligned .

The score (with clarinet in Bb) shows that the part version has a typo. The quarter note is supposed to be double-dotted.

Link to IMSLP page: https://imslp.org/wiki/3_Wind_Quartets%2C_Op.4_(Gambaro%2C_Vincenzo)

The original actually does have two dots ... just not exactly aligned as they should be.

@nuggethead …and poorly subdivided!

This is why no one uses double dots!

I've seen a lot of older scores where the dots on dotted notes (whether single or double) are located on the beat where the dotted part begins, rather than right next to the note.  This was standard notation for a while before it was changed to always be next to the note - precisely to avoid this kind of confusion.
